# Custom border layout contains half of a circle

Tags: android, xml, android-shapedrawable

I need create xml with two layout title and description.
In title layout I need add border have half of circle in bottom left and right, and with description layout border have half of circle in top left and right.
Here is my design

[image]

I can do it with create two half circle over line of rectangle radius border, but I don't want use this.
How I can do it with another solution?
Please give me key work or solution to do it!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#materialshapedrawable-and-shapeappearancemodel) defining a custom `CornerTreatment` to apply to the components.
Something like:

```
    val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius)
    val title_layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.title_layout)
    
    val titleShapeModel = ShapeAppearanceModel().toBuilder()
            .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .setBottomLeftCorner(ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment()).setBottomLeftCornerSize(radius)
            .setBottomRightCorner(ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment()).setBottomRightCornerSize(radius)
            .build()
    val titleBackground = MaterialShapeDrawable(titleShapeModel)
    titleBackground.setStroke(1f, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))

    ViewCompat.setBackground(title_layout, titleBackground)
```

where the `ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment` is:

```
class ConcaveRoundedCornerTreatment : CornerTreatment() {

    override fun getCornerPath(
            shapePath: ShapePath,
            angle: Float,
            interpolation: Float,
            radius: Float
    ) {
        val interpolatedRadius = radius * interpolation
        shapePath.reset(0f, interpolatedRadius, ANGLE_LEFT, ANGLE_LEFT - angle)
        shapePath.addArc(
                -interpolatedRadius,
                -interpolatedRadius,
                interpolatedRadius,
                interpolatedRadius,
                ANGLE_BOTTOM,
                -angle
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val ANGLE_LEFT = 180f
        const val ANGLE_BOTTOM = 90f
    }
}
```

Just do the same with the description layout:

[image]

If you are using a view like a `CardView` which has a built-in `shapeAppearanceModel`:

```
cardView.shapeAppearanceModel = cardView.shapeAppearanceModel.toBuilder()
        .setTopRightCorner(concaveRoundedCornerTreatment).
        .........
        .build()
```