# Android: Custom background - rectangle with a circle cutting in the middle

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, drawable

I'm trying to implement this view

[image]

As you can see it had a circle cutting to the left and right of the rectangle

I tried to use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
                android:topRightRadius="8dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" />

            <size
                android:width="300dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="290dp"
        android:top="40dp"
        android:bottom="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="290dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="40dp"
        android:bottom="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#EEEEEE"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but the result was not showing the cutting circle to the left and right

Is there any way to implement these cutting without loosing the shadow effect of the cart

Comment: Change the oval shape color you can see. However you won't get elevation. I suggest use background image it'll work.

Comment: I'd personally make an SVG of the image, import it to studio, and then use it as a background

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906494/custom-border-layout-contains-half-of-a-circle/62908122#62908122